# Is it possible to reorder the elements that generate the cover page in KOMA Script using the \maketitle command?

Tags: koma-script, titles, scrbook

Typically, the cover page elements available for the scrbook class, which are generated with the `\maketitle` command are:

```
\titlehead{title head}
\subject{subject}
\title{title}
\subtitle{subtitle}
\author{author\thanks{footnote}}
\date{date}
\publishers{publisher}
\uppertitleback{titlebackhead}
\lowertitleback{titlebackfoot}
\dedication{dedication}
```

and are usually printed in the same order. However, it may sometimes be useful to vary the order in which these elements are printed. I wonder if it would be possible to generate a cover page (and how) containing some of these elements in this order?

```
\title{title}
\subtitle{subtitle}
\subject{subject}
\author{author\thanks{footnote}}
\publishers{publisher}
\date{date}
\dedication{dedication}
```

I know that I can use these fields and place the content as I wish, but I am interested to know if there is a way to modify the order in which these elements appear.

Comment: KOMA-Script does not provide an interface to reorder the result of `\maketitle`. If you want title pages that differ from those provided by the class, it is recommended to use either freely formatted title pages using the `titlepage` environment or a package like [`uni-titlepage`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/uni-titlepage) (also from the KOMA-Script author) or [`titling`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titling). Alternatively you can copy the definition from the class file and change it. But note, using the internal macros of the original definition could break in future.